# GitHub pause in the middle of workflow action

Tags: github, yaml, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have created GitHub workflow. It deployed first on staging and than on the production environment on merge. What I want is to pause the deployment at staging, (so that I can do a quick sanity test on staging) and than I have some manual trigger to deploy to production.

Below is the workflow yml file.

```
name: main

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  test:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/build-test.yml
    secrets: inherit

  staging:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/staging-deploy.yml
    secrets: inherit

  prod:
    name: 'Deploy to Prod'
    uses: ./.github/workflows/deploy.yml
    needs: [test, staging]
    with:
      stage: prod
    secrets: inherit
```

Comment: You achieve this by adding a [deployment review](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/reviewing-deployments) job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Github Actions allows you to [review deployments](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/reviewing-deployments) by using environments.

First, you will need to [create an environment](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment#creating-an-environment) in the repository, and [add Reviewers](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment#required-reviewers) to it.

Then, you will need to add a job in your workflow asking for this approval before executing the deploy to production.

Example with an environment named `Prod` asking for review:

```
name: main

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  test:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/build-test.yml
    secrets: inherit

  staging:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/staging-deploy.yml
    secrets: inherit

  manual-approval:
    environment: 'Prod'
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    needs:
      - test
      - staging
    steps:
      - run: echo "Approved to Prod"

  prod:
    name: 'Deploy to Prod'
    uses: ./.github/workflows/deploy.yml
    needs: 
      - manual-approval
    with:
      stage: prod
    secrets: inherit
```

Answer (score -1):

To sleep for 3 seconds you can use

```
- name: Pause
  run: sleep 3
```